# What is the difference between cdnjs and npm?

Tags: javascript, npm, cdn

What is the difference between cdnjs and npm? Is npm a type of CDN (content delivery network)?

Comment: The two aren't related, Content Delivery Network vs. Node Package Manager. The first is a servers network that hosts content, the second is a software for maintaining Node.js packages.

Comment: I understand that cdns are hosted and npms are installed (needed to be downloaded). But I guess my question is cant you find most node packages hosted on a cdn and therefore use that in replace of it

Answer (score 2):

npm (Node Package Manager) is a repository consisting of Node.js modules (packages). You can search and download modules from it.

cdnjs is a Content Delivery Network (CDN) for JavaScript library files. You can add references of JavaScript libraries from cdnjs without requiring them to be on your server. Most, if not all, cdnjs libraries are available as a package on npm.

Answer (score -1):

npmjs == node js deps // **server** side

CDN == your browser deps // **client** side

in simple words

Comment: npm packages don't have to be server side. They can be anything really, but packages are usually CommonJS-compatible JS libraries.