# react-native: Reference external JS file

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am very new to React Native.  For the app that I am building, I need to use a JavaScript API.  The API documentation says to use this in an HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.4/esri/css/main.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.4/"></script>
```

Is it possible to reference these in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, I don't see a reason why you shouldn't. As [arcgis](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/) doesn't have a module registered, you can have the CDN reference in the higher level of your application. When you have a CDN referenced in your app, it is on the client-side, which means the browser will download the file, on the other hand, a module will be maintained on the server. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569064/whats-the-diff-between-cdnjs-vs-npmjs)

If you are looking for an alternative, I have found [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for React Native](https://github.com/glazou/react-native-arcgis-sdk-demo)

Answer (score 0):

you can try it's `node` package here [arcgis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/arcgis) as `react native` works with it